# How do I store data to the device?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to figure how to store my application's data for the long term. Basically I get a list of data from from a web service, and I don't want to go back to the web service the next time the app runs. I'd prefer to just store it locally. How do I do this?

I don't mind serialising the data to any particular format. I don't see this on the Xamarin site for Android. There's a tutorial for iOS, but I'm not interested in that.

Comment: here's a good tutorial on Sqlite: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: that vogella guy - he's already dug me out of a few holes! I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: Creating and maintaining a database just for a JSON response is maybe too much? What do you think?

Comment: I have lots more data to store, but I felt it was unnecessary to outline it all in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally copy the data from webservice in raw format in a text file on the memory.

So, I have just to open the inputStream from the file the same I did from the webservice and my code remains clean.

But I guess there are indeed thousands of ways to copy this data.
I just wanted to share the one I found more convenient.

The code just for information:

```
InputStream source = getStreamFromWebservice();// <= YOUR CODE HERE
File dir = context.getDir("CACHE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, fileName);
// Write to Memory
try {
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    int read;
    try {
        while ((read = source.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            f.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    f.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```